# How can I check Permission for GeoLocationClass into MainActivity?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-permissions

I am getting Permission checks on

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_PROVIDER_UPDATE_RATE,
                LOCATION_PROVIDER_UPDATE_DISTANCE, locationListener);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                LOCATION_PROVIDER_UPDATE_RATE,
                LOCATION_PROVIDER_UPDATE_DISTANCE, locationListener);
    }

---------------------------

}
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

I have added the permission checks for the above location managers in my `GeoLocationHelper` class. Now its Returning me Required Context on "this". How can I get the permission from my `MainActivity` and pass it to the permission check in `GeoLocationHelper` class

```
void stopRetrievingLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to pass the `Context` to your `GeoLocationHelper` class

```
public class GeoLocationHelper{
    private Context mContext;

    public GeoLocationHelper(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    ----------
}
```

Then change your `stopRetrievingLocation` function like :

```
void stopRetrievingLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

And on your `MainActivity`

```
GeoLocationHelper mGeoLocationHelper = new GeoLocationHelper(this);
```